# Web Parts & User Instance without SQL Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-3.5, web-parts, user-instance

I'm having hard times with the SQL Error

> Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed.

No matter what I do (yes, I have the SQL Express running in the Local account and deleted the SQLExpress folder on Local Profile), users under Windows 2008 always get this issue and sometimes on Vista as well (not that frequent).

**I do need to find other ideas!**

I was thinking move to **SQLite** (as there is a wonderful [Provider](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adodotnetsqlite/)) or even use **XML** file instead.

All I do is manage WebParts as panels that each user can modify their visibility and place. When done editing it saves automatically into the user instance.

I need only this functionality but I can't find a decent way to drop SQL Express 2005 User Instances ... any ideas?

Any help is highly appreciated, *Thank you*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked for webhosting company where SQL Express was used for freehosting users. We never experienced this problem so it must be some weird combination of parameters.

I suggest to do some probing

- Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to trace which files/directories/registry entries is SQL Express trying to access when the error occurs. Using this utility you can also locate problems with access rights.
- Look into SQL Express log located in C:\Documents and Settings\user_name\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS for some additional info
- Make sure you have user instances enabled running this on SQL express default instance
  `sp_configure 'user instances enabled', '1'`
- Just for sure I would try to list all user instances and eventually try to connect to one.

  To list user instances connect to default one (usually named COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS) and run: 
  `SELECT instance_pipe_name 
  FROM sys.dm_os_child_instances`.
  Then use value in instance_pipe_name with sqlcmd utility: 
  `C:>sqlcmd -S np:\.\pipe\69651E0A-5550-46\tsql\query`. 
  Now you are connected to user instance. Try to execute some DML.
- You probably did this but for sure have a look in Windows Event Viewer

If nothing comes up from probing you can always create database using snandard way on SQL Express default instance (connect to server, create database, setup connection string and use it instead of database.mdf in your solution).

Comment: +1 fantastic "how to" steps ... bottom line was that I turn my self into SQLite and I have no problems now :) and SQLite file has only 9Kb against 4Mb minimum from mdb file. :)

Comment: I am glad that you find a suitable solution :)

Answer (score -1):

Using "microsoft sql server compact 3.5" gives you almost any of the normal sqlexpress functionality while being easily portable without a real server to be put on.

http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx

Unless you're doing a big and complex application (lots of stored procedures, triggers and such), its a nice way to work.

Here's some other information :

http://blogs.msdn.com/stevelasker/archive/2006/11/27/sql-server-compact-edition-under-asp-net-and-iis.aspx

Comment: -1 User Instance feature is a SQL Express feature, it is not available in Compact edition

Comment: For what you're doing using sql express is overkill. You can simply do a single database with the compact version where users can save their config identified by session ID.
But hey, its your call. bye ;)